# Can I increase an existing field in MySQL by one using gorm? Without using raw SQL

Tags: mysql, grails-orm

If I use the raw SQL, it would be "UPDATE table_name SET field1 = field1 + 1 WHERE id = an_id_val";

How can I achieve the same thing with func chain calls like db.Update() or db.Save() etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sql expression

```
    DB.Model(&your_model).UpdateColumn("field1 ", gorm.Expr("field1  + ?", 1))
```

http://gorm.io/docs/update.html